Postfix testing fails
I need help with postfix. Testing with this command:
echo "test email" | mail -s  "test email" jeff@m1.lan```

Doesn't produce output in /var/mail/jeff
postfix is running:
sudo postfix status
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is running: PID: 8781

I also don't see postfix log activity in /var/log/ or via:
 sudo log stream --predicate 'sender == "postfix"'

My main.cf file is included.
compatibility_level = 2
queue_directory = /private/var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = _postfix
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
setgid_group = _postdrop
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/examples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
message_size_limit = 10485760
mailbox_size_limit = 0
biff = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
myhostname = m1.lan
mydestination = m1.lan, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myorigin  = m1.lan
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/24 172.18.0.0/16 172.19.0.0/16 172.17.0.0/16
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
default_transport = smtp
relay_transport = smtp
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination


Testing with telnet:
jeff@m1 Desktop $ telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 m1.lan ESMTP Postfix
ehlo localhost
mail from: jeff@localhost
rcpt to: jeff@localhost
data
Subject: My first mail on Postfix

hello world
250-m1.lan
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10485760
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 SMTPUTF8
250 2.1.0 Ok
250 2.1.5 Ok
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>

.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 016CF5AB29C7
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
jeff@m1 Desktop $ mailq
Mail queue is empty


mail(1) is not the same as sendmail(1). It doesn't read the standard input. Enter the mail command, then the message on one or more new lines, then control-D on a line by itself to send.

Yes, I tried with telnet (documented above) and as you see it's not working. Additionally, I have no idea where any of this is being logged.

The hostname has to be resolvable for Postfix to work. Do you have a valid DNS setup?

Doesn't /etc/hosts suffice for testing on localhost?

Maybe it would help if you explained what you're trying to accomplish with PF. What is your use for it?
